# Office 365 how to hide ribbion

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, office-365, css, suite-links

I want to hide ribbon like :- Outlook, Calendar, People etc in below print screen marked in red round I want to hide only these options. Please advice.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharepoint designer to modify the master page and hide the top ribbon. Refer to [this](http://rahulklst.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/sharepoint-2013-hiding-top-office365-bar-and-ribbon-for-non-admin-users-of-sharepoint-2013-site/) post. You can also hide it for users with specific permissions using SPSecurityTrimmedControl . Refer [this](http://support.bind.pt/entries/24005833-How-can-I-hide-the-Office-365-SharePoint-2013-suite-and-ribbon-bars-for-anonymous-users-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your master page :

```
.o365cs-base.o365cst.o365spo .o365cs-topnavLinkBackground {        
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to hide the elements. First create a new css file with name ex: Custom.css and place it inside the site assets library.

Then add following to your HTML master page:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CSSCustom" Name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/SiteAssets/Custom.css %&gt;" runat="server" After="Themable/corev15.css"/>-->
```

Now edit the custom.css file and add following

```
#O365_MainLink_ShellMail {
    display:none;
}
#O365_MainLink_ShellCalendar  {
    display:none;
}
#O365_MainLink_ShellPeople  {
    display:none;
}
#O365_MainLink_ShellNewsfeed  {
    display:none;
}
#O365_MainLink_ShellDocuments {
    display:none;
}
#O365_MainLink_ShellSites  {
    display:none;
}
#O365_MainLink_ShellTasks {
    display:none;
}
#O365_MainLink_ShellAdmin {
    display:none;
}
```